# Login System & Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-management

I'm writing a simple asp.net application with the entity framework and mvc.

I started with a template which actually includes a simple account creation and login system. However I wish to store account details in a database.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
```

I want to ask these two things

1. Can I use the UserManager class to store and manage users in my own database structure?
2. Where is the example (default .net mvc application) storing username / password?

Comment: You can create the asp.net tables inside your database, and from there you can manipulate if you like.

Comment: I would suggest you to make your own login system. Why? Because you will be able to do what ever you want with that login system.

Comment: @Gohomeurdrunk this seems like a waste of time when you can use the Asp membership and if you really want you can create a custom version of it and then do what you want. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Gohomeurdrunk: Unless you have an exceptional business case to create a custom auth system, it's a *hugely* bad idea to do so. Auth is *hard*. It seems straight-forward, but to do it right, with proper security, encryption, etc. is a tall order. You take something like Identity or SimpleMembership, with millions of people using it day in and day out, the code becomes incredibly hardened, because there's teams of individuals working on it and bugs are squashed relatively quickly. Your system will not have that.

Comment: @DaleFraser: 1) What do you mean by "my own database structure"? Please be specific. 2) The project scaffold for an MVC5 project with Individual Authentication is your example. It has all the logic there for creating users and setting passwords. What are you missing/not understanding?

Comment: Where does it go, I have an account which it is storing somewhere, but where. Normally account details would live in the database so I can reference them. I at the very least need to know where it is storing this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, or my guess, you are using ASP.Net MVC 5 and that is the scaffold code.

1. Can I use the UserManager class to store and manage users in my own database structure? 
   Yes, you can use the UserManager object to store users. First thing you would want to do is open IdentityModels.cs and modify the class to add in any extra fields if needed:

   ```
   public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

   {
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       //Etc
   }
   ```

Where is the example (default .net mvc application) storing username / password?
Have a look at your web.config. An example of what I have on my dev machine:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20140606091757.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20140606091757;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What this means is that you need to connect to your datasource specified in your web.config. In Visual Studio click on show all files:

[image: Show all files in VS 2013]

Then, double click on the mdf file which will open up the server explorer. Browse to the AspNetUsers table:

[image: Browse DB]

Comment: Amazing how you can get so many dumb answers then one helpful person comes along, thanks.